# How would you run "watch" command for "one minute" and then exit?

Tags: bash, watch

I'm trying to use "watch" command `watch -n1 './script.sh'` that runs every second for 1 minute then stops. How would you achive this by using pipeline or very short for/while loop. Thanks.

Comment: `watch` will normally run until interrupted. If you want `watch` to exit on an error from the program running use the `-e` or `--errexit` options, which will cause watch to exit if the return value from the program is non-zero. (Source: man page)

Comment: There is no errors :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found one way is by using "timeout"

```
timeout -sHUP 1m watch -n1 ./script.sh
```

Any one knows any other ways ?