# How to run watch command in bash in CI environment?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-cli, watch

I'm trying to run `watch` bash command in a CI. How do you run it if you can't actually stop it?

Just to make a real example. I'm trying to run `watch` command against `aws cloudformation describe-stack-events`. The point is that I don't know how to stop it inside a CI.

Comment: Are you looking for getting a confirmation when stack creation is complete?

Comment: I know that it exists `aws cloudformation wait` but I want to have something that show me the status of cloudformation create/update stack in the CI console

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997584/how-would-you-run-watch-command-for-one-minute-and-then-exit

Comment: `watch` is not a `bash` command.

Comment: @chepner fixed ;-)